# Incorrect trailing return type

Tags: c++11, c++14, trailing-return-type

I already have a code that works fine with C++ 14 but now I need to set my compiler settings to C++ 11.

```
    auto LookupPredicate(const std::string& aUnitId)
    {
        return [aUnitId](Coach* pCoach) {return aUnitId == pCoach->getUnitId();};
    }

    template<typename C, typename UnaryPredicate>
    auto findIn_impl(C& container, UnaryPredicate p) {
        return std::find_if(std::begin(container), std::end(container), p);
    }

findCoach(const std::string& aUnitId)
{
    auto it = findIn_impl(_Coaches, LookupPredicate(aUnitId));
    if( it != std::end(_Coaches))
                    cout<<"Selected Unit must exist. Incorrect value of aUnitId = " << aUnitId);
    return **it;
}
```

So, I made the following changes

```
auto LookupPredicate(const std::string& aUnitId) -> bool
    {
        return [aUnitId](Coach* pCoach) {return aUnitId == pCoach->getUnitId();};
    }
```

Added a trailing return type bool..
But I get errors like
 error: cannot convert '{anonymous}::LookupPredicate(const string&)::' to 'bool' in return
Any idea what must be the trailing type for this

Comment: You return a lambda, not a book. I think you should return std:: function

Comment: Thanks @JVApen How do I have a trailing type as a lambda in this case.

Comment: @KaranShah: You can't. You cannot type the typename of a lambda. That's *why* the C++14 version had to use `auto` return type deduction. Without that feature, you *cannot* return a lambda directly; you'd have to use a wrapper type like `std::function`.

Comment: Also note that returning std::function instead of a lambda will have a performance overhead (because std::function is a virtual call wrapper on top of your lambda)